# DESCOMPONER FECHA Y CONCATENARLA SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

BUEN DIA.

REQUIERO SACAR EL AÑO, EL MES Y EL DIA DE UNA FECHA DE UN CAMPO DATE DE UNA BASE DE DATOS EN SQL SERVER PARA CREAR UN CAMPO LLAMADO FOLIO QUE SE COMPONE DE 'C-'+AAMMDD. DONDE AA SON LOS ULTIMOS DOS DIGITOS DEL AÑO, MM SON LOS DIGITOS DEL MES Y DD SON LOS DIAS (EN AMBOS CASOS REQUIERO QUE SI ES MENOR A 10, SE CONSERVE EL 0 A LA IZQUIERDA).

EJEMPLO:

SI TENGO LA SIGUIENTE FECHA = 2022/01/01
EL FOLIO QUEDARIA DE LA SIGUIENTE MANERA: C-220101

DE ANTEMANO GRACIAS POR SU ATENCION.

Comment: Se acostumbra mostrar un avance de codigo, algo que hayas hecho para poder ayudarte mejor.

Pero puedes hacer SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), DAY(GETDATE())

Comment: De acuerdo amigo, lo tomare en cuenta, muchas gracias por tu comentario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar CONVERT para darle formato especifico a una fecha, se usa de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT CONVERT (data_type(length)),Date, DateFormatCode)
```

Tomando en cuenta la salida que quieres, el DateFormatCode que te serviria seria el numero 12 cuya salida es en YYDDMM y simplemente lo concatenas con 'C-'

```
SELECT 'C-' + CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),12)
```

La lista de los DateFormatCode los puedes ver aca [Date and Time Conversions Using SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)

Comment: Si me sirvió la solución que me diste, muchas gracias amigo!!!